# Como faço para mudar de classe para função nesse caso

Tags: react, funções, next.js

Sou novo na área e estou com dificuldade de conseguir passar o código abaixo para função.

Todas as formas que tentei dá problema em event.

```
import React from 'react'
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';


export default class youtube extends React.Component {

   render() {
      const opts = {
        playerVars: {
          // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
          autoplay: 1,
        },
      };

      return (
         <div className={styles.body}>
            <div className={styles.tamanhovideoyoutube}>
               <YouTube className={styles.tamanhovideodentroyoutube} videoId="soXDzGHls_c" opts={opts} title={"title"} onReady={this._onReady}/>
            <h4 className='px-0.5 py-0.5 ml-1 font-bold'>Veja o vídeo no YouTube <a className='text-blue-600' href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soXDzGHls_c">aqui</a> </h4>
            </div>


        </div>    
      )}


   _onReady(event) {
      // access to player in all event handlers via event.target
      event.target.pauseVideo();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
import React from 'react';
import Youtube from 'react-youtube';

const youtube = () => {
  const opts = {
    playerVars: {
      // https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters
      autoplay: 1,
    },
  };

  const _onReady = (event) => {
    // access to player in all event handlers via event.target
    event.target.pauseVideo();
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.body}>
      <div className={styles.tamanhovideoyoutube}>
        <YouTube
          className={styles.tamanhovideodentroyoutube}
          videoId="soXDzGHls_c"
          opts={opts}
          title={'title'}
          onReady={_onReady}
        />
        <h4 className="px-0.5 py-0.5 ml-1 font-bold">
          Veja o vídeo no YouTube{' '}
          <a
            className="text-blue-600"
            href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soXDzGHls_c"
          >
            aqui
          </a>{' '}
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default youtube;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).